# What is the purpose of this line of code?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Consider this snippet of Objective-C:

```
NSString *elementString = nil;

if(elementText != NULL) {
    elementString = [NSString stringWithCString:(char*)elementText encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [elementString self]; 
    xmlFree(elementText);
}
```

I understand that `[elementString self]` returns a reference to `elementString`.  My question is, since that return value isn't being used here, why would `[elementString self]` be called at all?

This pattern is repeated many times throughout the XML parsing routines in an application I'm maintaining.  If it only happened once I would just suspect somebody did something silly, but given its prevalence I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Edit: The answer given by Benedict Cohen is correct.  The `elementString` variable isn't ever used.  Most instances of this pattern are buried in multi-hundred line methods and I didn't see that it was never used.

Comment: Can you provide more than a snippet?  Otherwise the line of code you reference is simply suppressing compiler warnings.

Comment: I've never seen this before. Where are you seeing it such that you consider it "prevalent"?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: When I said 'prevalent', I meant within this app I'm maintaining.  Instances of this pattern exist in 125 different class files.

Comment: Looks like whoever wrote that code was cargo culting it...

Comment: Indeed.  It was also very heavily copied-and-pasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the compiler would issue a warning that `elementString` is not used.

Edit: Actually, due to the way that `elementString` is declared and then set I don't think this would raise a warning....

Edit: Just tested it. `[elementString self]` isn't suppressing a warning. My only guess is that it was once included to suppress a warning but the code has been refactored and it's no longer necessary.